# Query slow if wrong precision for a decimal parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am using SqlParameter for passing values to my query

Assume I have a field `DOS numeric(3,0)` in my table.

My query is something like `SELECT * FROM ENT WHERE ENT.DOS = @DOS`.

The problem is that I don't know the type of the field ENT.DOS at runtime (my engine is very complicated...), so I don't specify any precision or scale when I create the SqlParameter.

For exemple, if I want DOS = 1, Precision will be set at 1 and Scale at 0.

It works, that's not the point. The problem is : it's slow.

If I specify the real Precision and Scale values, the query runs fast.

I can reproduce the problem in Management Studio :

In the database : 
DOS = numeric(3,0)
TICOD = char(1)
PICOD = numeric(8,0)
PINO = numeric(8,0)
ENT_ID = int

Slow version :

```
DECLARE @DOS as numeric(1,0) = 1
DECLARE @TICOD as varchar(1) = 'C'
DECLARE @PICOD as numeric(1,0) = 3
DECLARE @PINO as numeric(8,0) = 99999999
DECLARE @ENT_ID as numeric(8,0) = 99999999


SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM ENT AS ENT WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE
(CE4 = '1') and (
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD = @PICOD and PINO < @PINO ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD < @PICOD ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD < @TICOD ) or
( DOS< @DOS )
)
order by DOS desc,TICOD desc,PICOD desc,PINO desc,ENT_ID desc
OPTION (FAST 1)
```

Fast version (with the proper types for the parameters):

```
declare @DOS as numeric(3,0) = 1
declare @TICOD as char(1) = 'C'
declare @PICOD as numeric(5,0) = 3
declare @PINO as numeric(8,0) = 99999999
declare @ENT_ID as int = 99999999


SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM ENT AS ENT WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE
(CE4 = '1') and (
(DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD = @PICOD and PINO = @PINO and ENT_ID < @ENT_ID ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD = @PICOD and PINO < @PINO ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD < @PICOD ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD < @TICOD ) or
( DOS< @DOS )
)
order by DOS desc,TICOD desc,PICOD desc,PINO desc,ENT_ID desc
OPTION (FAST 1)
```

So my question is : is there a way to declare SqlParameter for decimal types without specifying Precision and Scale and have a query that runs fast ?

**UPDATE 1 :**

Execution plans :

**Correct Datatypes:** 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14168890/SqlParameter/exec_plan_fast.sqlplan

[image]

The plan shows seek predicates

```
1 Seek Keys1: End: DOS < @DOS, 
2 Seek Keys1: Prefix: DOS = @DOS, End: TICOD < @TICOD, 
3 Seek Keys1: Prefix: DOS, TICOD = @DOS, @TICOD, End: PICOD < @PICOD, 
4 Seek Keys1: Prefix: DOS, TICOD, PICOD = @DOS, @TICOD, @PICOD, End: PINO < @PINO, 
5 Seek Keys1: Prefix: DOS, TICOD, PICOD, PINO = @DOS, @TICOD, @PICOD, @PINO, End: ENT_ID < @ENT_ID
```

**Non matching Datatypes:** https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14168890/SqlParameter/exec_plan_slow.sqlplan

[image]

The plan shows a scan with the predicate moving into a filter.

**Non matching Datatypes `(FORCESEEK)`:** https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14168890/SqlParameter/exec_plan_forceseek.sqlplan

[image]

The index GTFENT_G is : DOS,TICOD,PICOD,PINO,ENT_ID

Also, I also tested to declare numerical values which are in fact integer in integer type, the slow one become fast.

Comment: Can you post the actual execution plans for slow and fast versions?

Comment: are you sure `DECLARE @TICOD as varchar(1) = 'C'` is `varchar` and not `nvarchar`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, I'm sure ;)

Comment: What if you change the `WITH (NOLOCK)` to `WITH(FORCESEEK, NOLOCK)`?

Comment: For the fast version, no changes, but for the slow one, it's the same, but the query plan is completely different : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14168890/SqlParameter/exec_plan_forceseek.sqlplan

Comment: @MartinSmith No problem;) I temporarily used an Integer if the value is an integer. But I could not do testing until Tuesday ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the faster version the five seek operations all get combined into one seek operator in the plan.

The index is ordered `DOS asc,TICOD asc,PICOD asc,PINO asc,ENT_ID asc`.

Because you want the `TOP 1 ... ORDER BY DOS desc,TICOD desc,PICOD desc,PINO desc,ENT_ID desc` it just needs to seek the 5 different index ranges in descending key order and stop as soon as it finds the first matching row.

In the slower version with the mismatched datatypes whilst all of the predicates remain seekable individually it seems unable to combine them into this single seek operator. The plan with the `FORCESEEK` hint shows all the individual range seeks carried out by separate seek operators.

Moreover it no longer takes advantage of index order to avoid a sort or to short circuit as soon as the `TOP 1` is found. The seek operators are all under a blocking sort operator which mean they are all evaluated in their entirety.

It would obviously be preferable to simply use the correct datatypes as per the column definition. If this *really* is impossible then one workaround seems to be to declare them as `numeric(38,S)`.

It doesn't seem to matter too much what `S` is. So this can just be based on the number of decimals in the data. The key seems to be ensuring that the datatype of the variable has at least equal *precision* to that of the column.

Declaring `@DOS` and `@PICOD` as `numeric(38,37)` or `numeric(38,0)` both worked to give the faster plan shape against the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ENT](
    [FOO] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [CE4] INT,
    [DOS] [numeric](3,0) NOT NULL,
    [TICOD] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [PICOD] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [PINO] [numeric](8, 0) NOT NULL,
    [ENT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([DOS] ASC, [TICOD] ASC, [PICOD] ASC, [PINO] ASC, [ENT_ID] ASC)
)
```

Query

```
DECLARE @DOS as numeric(38,37) = 1
DECLARE @TICOD as varchar(1) = 'C'
DECLARE @PICOD as numeric(38,37) = 3
DECLARE @PINO as numeric(8,0) = 99999999
DECLARE @ENT_ID as numeric(8,0) = 99999999


SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM ENT AS ENT WITH(NOLOCK, FORCESEEK) 
WHERE
 (
DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD = @PICOD and PINO = @PINO and ENT_ID < @ENT_ID ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD = @PICOD and PINO < @PINO ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD = @TICOD and PICOD < @PICOD ) or
( DOS = @DOS and TICOD < @TICOD ) or
( DOS< @DOS )

order by DOS desc,TICOD desc,PICOD desc,PINO desc,ENT_ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you got your declrations for your slow example, but if `DECLARE @TICOD as varchar(1) = 'C'` is really `DECLARE @TICOD as nvarchar(1) = 'C'` then it is not the size of the decimal that is biting you, actually it is likely your indexes of `TICOD` not being used.

When you need to compare two different data types one of the two types needs to be converted to the other data type so a comparison can be made. Sql Server uses [this order](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) for figuring out who to convert, lower items on the list get moved to higher items on the list.

So looking at the list we see we have

```
25. nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )    
26. nchar
27. varchar (including varchar(max) )
28. char
29. varbinary (including varbinary(max) )
```

so in your slow version when you do `TICOD = @TICOD` it will turn `TICOD` in to a `nvarchar` instead of turning `@TICOD` in to a `char`.

Because `TICOD` is converted **the query will no longer use any indexes built with `TICOD`**, that is where your slowness is coming from.

I would change the input type from `nvarchar` to `char` or `varchar` (as using varchar instead of nvarchar would also use the index) passing `SqlDbType.Char` or `SqlDbType.VarChar` in to whatever [`SqlParameter` creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you use when you create it in .NET.

Comment: Seeking on a `char` column with a  `varchar` parameter/variable/literal doesn't prevent index use.

Comment: Rather than putting a CAST everywhere @TICOD is used, I would DECLARE and CAST new variables at the top to match the datatypes used by the table.   Look at the query execution plan to see if the fast query is using an index that the slow query isn't using.

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right, however I did find the gotcha, it does not use the index with `nvarchar` and if you auto-detect the type with `SqlParameter` it uses `nvarchar` by default. I have updated my post accordingly. [Here is a quick pastebin](http://pastebin.com/q7V0ze3r) to show the query side of it.

Comment: For the input parameter, I am using DbType.AnsiString, which is a varchar. But you're right, if I change char(1) to nvarchar(1) in the fast version, it become also slow.

Answer (score 0):

how do you measure the slowness? did you clean buffer-pools and proc cache before running both queries? also what is the exact execution time? does faster version completes in few seconds and slower version takes few minutes/hours/not completing ?

ideally when you use local variables in where clause of query, they should be accurate or large in data-type compare to the actual column Data-type. if the data type is happen to be smaller; then optimizer will not be able to use indexes even if it is there because of implicit cast/convert/round/trunc etc.. operation on the Left side of the Where condition. And you might know the table column participating in to where condition should use as it is w/o applying any explicit/implicit function  on it.

Try to using larger Precision and Scale for all NUMERIC variables or use **SQL_VARIANT data type** for the variable declared locally before they get value assigned and used in query. that should help in avoiding overhead of implicit conversion.

also two of the Variable is completely declared as different data type. ENT_ID is INT and you declared it as NUMERIC. column TICOD  is CHAR(1) and you declare it as Varchar(1). i am still ok with TICOD   as is CHAR is compare against VARCHAR but INT Vs NUMERIC is definitely not good. that why i suggested SQL_VARIANT data type.

Comment: For the slowness, when I hit F5, one is instant, the other takes 1 sec (with or without any cache).